# C++ stopped working out of nowhere in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So, c++ stopped working out of nowhere today, I can't seem to build a file anymore, but it was working fine yesterday.

Error: The cppbuild task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:

```
{
    "type": "cppbuild",
    "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
    "command": "C:\\MINGW32\\bin\\g++.exe",
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "C:\\MINGW32\\bin"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
    ],
    "group": "build",
    "detail": "compilador: C:\\MINGW32\\bin\\g++.exe"
}
```

The task will be ignored.

This is the error that it shows.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try re-installing your MINGW? Normally, that solves the problem